# Calculating travel times in R for several pair of addresses

Tags: r, react-google-maps-api, travel-time

I am a newbie on this. I'm following tutorials and instructions as much as I can, and I get not results. The problem may not be in code (I think), but on what happens of the google maps API side.

I get 'no travel time' for each of my rows.

This is my code:

```
api_key <- 'IthinkIshouldNdtTellYOU'

desired_arrival_time <- as.POSIXct(paste(next_wednesday, "09:00:00"), tz = "America/New_York")
arrival_epoch_time <- as.numeric(desired_arrival_time)


 get_travel_time <- function(origin, destination, api_key, arrival_time) {
  base_url <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
  query <- paste0("origin=", URLencode(origin),
              "&destination=", URLencode(destination),
              "&mode=transit",
              "&arrival_time=", arrival_time,
              "&key=", api_key)
 response <- GET(paste0(base_url, query))

if (response$status_code == 200) {
data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(response$content))
if (length(data$routes) > 0) {
  travel_time <- data$routes[[1]]$legs[[1]]$duration$text
  return(travel_time)
} else {
  return(NA)
}
} else {
stop("API request failed with status code: ", response$status_code)
}
}

address_pairs$travel_time <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(address_pairs)) {
 travel_time_result <- try(
   get_travel_time(
   origin = address_pairs$OriginAdd[i],
   destination = address_pairs$DestinAdd[i],
   api_key = api_key,
   arrival_time = arrival_epoch_time
),
silent = TRUE  # Set silent = TRUE to not print error messages directly
)

if (class(travel_time_result) == "try-error") {
    address_pairs$travel_time[i] <- NA
    print(paste("Error on row", i, ":", travel_time_result))
} else {
    # If no error, check if get_travel_time returns a value
    if (!is.na(travel_time_result) && length(travel_time_result) > 0) {
        address_pairs$travel_time[i] <- travel_time_result
    } else {
        # Assign NA if get_travel_time returns NA or length zero
        address_pairs$travel_time[i] <- NA
        print(paste("No travel time returned for row", i))
    }
}

Sys.sleep(0.2) # Be mindful of rate limiting by the API
}
```

This is what I get for each row. I cannot understand anything in my google cloud account. Is this costing me money? Did I overpass my quotas already?

> No travel time returned for row 1208"
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEwRg.png) "No travel time returned for row 1209"
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEwRg.png) "No travel time returned for row 1210"

I tried creating a function of time of travel, and then running a loop to calculate time of travel using that function. I used a lot of ChatGPT for this.

I can see the API key being queried but I get not even one result.

My addresses are NYC addresses. Google Maps works pretty fine here. Rstudio seems to query google maps as it takes a long time, but showing no results.

[image: Origin and destination addresses sample]

```
OriginAdd                           DestinAdd
365 Fifth Ave, Manhattan, New York  120 Schermerhorn St, Brooklyn, NY 11201
3280 46th Avenue, Queens, Corona, NY    265 E 161 St, Bronx, NY 10451
106-05 37 Avenue, Queens, New York .    125-01 Queens Blvd, Queens, NY 11415
3280 46th Street, Queens, NY    265 E 161 St, Bronx, NY 10451
475 48th Ave, Queens, New York 11109    100 Centre St, New York, NY 10013
```